# Solving $8v_{\xi\eta} - v_\xi - v_\eta = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

While solving a Goursat problem I stumbled upon this PDE. Can't solve it: $$8v_{\xi\eta} - v_\xi - v_\eta = 0$$

This is what I tried:

$v \rightarrow V e^{\alpha x + \beta x}$

$v_\xi = V_\xi e^{\alpha x + \beta x} + \alpha V e^{\alpha x + \beta x}$

$v_\xi = V_\eta e^{\alpha x + \beta x} + \beta V e^{\alpha x + \beta x}$

$v_{\xi\eta} = V_{\xi\eta} e^{\alpha x + \beta x} +\beta V_\xi e^{\alpha x + \beta x} + \alpha V_\eta e^{\alpha x + \beta x} + \alpha \beta V e^{\alpha x + \beta x}$

Replacing these in the equation and simplifying by $e^{\alpha x + \beta x}$ I got:

$$
V_{\xi\eta} + (\beta -1) V_\xi + (\alpha - 1) V_\eta + \alpha\beta V - \alpha V - \beta V = 0
$$

And we get a not solvable system:
$
\begin{cases}
\alpha - 1 = 0 \\
\alpha \beta - \alpha - \beta = 0
\end{cases}
$, so I can't get rid of $V_\xi$, $V$ or $V_\eta$, $V$.